# エクセル2000で作成したアニメーション用VBAを2010で動かしたい

Tags: vba

エクセル2000で作成したアニメーション用のVBAですが、
最近のエクセル2010ではアニメーション表示はVBAのコードが変更されているためか動きません。

エクセル2000でないと動きませんが、2010でも動くようにするには何処を変更すれば良いのか分かりませんでした。
ご知見を伺いたく投稿しました。

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ND, NEX, i As Integer
Dim T, UD(1 To 20), RUD(1 To 20), KY(1 To 20), RR(1 To 20), DF(1 To 20) As Single
Dim ABC, FN As String

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(10000, 150)).ClearContents
ABC = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value
If Right(ABC, 1) <> "¥" Then
ABC = ABC + "¥"
End If
FN = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value
Open ABC + FN For Input As #1
Input #1, ND
Input #1, NEX
ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value = ND
ActiveSheet.Range("B6") = NEX
For i = 1 To NEX
For j = 1 To ND
Input #1, T, UD(j), RUD(j), KY(j), RR(j), DF(j)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7 * j).Value = T
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7 * j + 1).Value = UD(j)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7 * j + 2).Value = RUD(j)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7 * j + 3).Value = KY(j)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7 * j + 4).Value = RR(j)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7 * j + 5).Value = DF(j) / 120
Next j
Next i
Close #1

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim TIT,WB As String
Dim i, j, ND, NEX As Integer
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Dim ERC1, ERC2 As Range
WB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set Sht1 = Worksheets("表示")
ND = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value
NEX = ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value
i = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value
j = 4 + 7 * i
Set ERC1 = Sht1.Range(Cells(1, j + 1), Cells(NEX, j + 1))
Set ERC2 = Sht1.Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(NEX, j))
TIT = StrConv(Str(i), vbWide) + "777"

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("グラフ2").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
With ActiveChart
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = TIT
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ERC1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ERC2
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Windows(WB).Activate
Set Sht1 = Nothing
Set ERC1 = Nothing
Set ERC2 = Nothing
Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Range("A1:F27").Select
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
Range("A1:C2").Select

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim NE, ND As Integer
Dim i, j, k, Speed As Integer
Dim X1, X2, X3, Z, DT, A As Single
Dim st1 As Worksheet
Set st1 = Worksheets("表示")

NE = st1.Range("B6").Value
ND = st1.Range("B5").Value
DT = st1.Range("G1").Value
A = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value
Speed = 11 - ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value

Z = 162
For k = 1 To NE
X1 = 162 + st1.Cells(k, 8).Value * A
If ND > 1 Then
X2 = 162 + st1.Cells(k, 15).Value * A
End If
If ND = 3 Then
X3 = 162 + st1.Cells(k, 22).Value * A
End If
If ND = 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 7").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, X1, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, X1 - 30, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 4, X1 + 54, 130.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 5, X1 + 138, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 6, X1, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 7, X1 + 108, 160.5
End If
If ND = 2 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 2").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, X1, 228.75
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, X1 + 108, 228.75
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 7").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 1, X1, 228.75
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 8, X1 + 108, 228.75

Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, X2, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, X2 - 30, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 4, X2 + 54, 130.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 5, X2 + 138, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 6, X2, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 7, X2 + 108, 160.5
End If
If ND = 3 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 11").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, X1, 297#
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, X1 + 108, 297#

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 2").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 1, X1, 297#
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 4, X1 + 108, 297#

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 2").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, X2, 228.75
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, X2 + 108, 228.75

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 7").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 1, X2, 228.75
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 8, X2 + 108, 228.75

Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, X3, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, X3 - 30, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 4, X3 + 54, 130.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 5, X3 + 138, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 6, X3, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 7, X3 + 108, 160.5
End If

Range("a10").Value = DT * k

For i = 1 To 100
For j = 1 To Speed * 100
dummy = i + j
Next j
Next i

Next k
Set st1 = Nothing
Range("a10").Select

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 2").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 1, 162, 297
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, 162, 228.75
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, 162 + 108, 228.75
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 4, 162 + 108, 297

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Freeform 7").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 1, 162, 228.75
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 8, 162 + 108, 228.75

Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 2, 162, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 3, 162 - 30, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 4, 162 + 54, 130.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 5, 162 + 138, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 6, 162, 160.5
Selection.ShapeRange.Nodes.SetPosition 7, 162 + 108, 160.5
ND = Worksheets("表示").Range("B5").Value
If ND = 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 12").Top = 228.75
End If
If ND = 2 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 12").Top = 297#
End If
If ND = 3 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 12").Top = 365.25
End If
Range("a10").Value = 0!
Range("B7").Select
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
ActiveSheet.Range("C5") = ScrollBar1.Value
ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: エラーメッセージ等は通知されないのでしょうか？ 通知されているならその内容を省略などせず表示されたままを追記してみてください。あとどの辺の処理までは動作しているか、どこから動作していないかとか調査はされていますか？ 直接参考にならないかもしれませんが、検索するとこんな記事が出てきます。[本当にあったVBAツール開発業務で困った話](https://qiita.com/ft0220/items/e003c2a2d71bf0a5d1ec), [応答が停止したExcelで、VBAを確実に中断させる方法](https://www.excel-chunchun.com/entry/2019/01/13/010851), [VBA デバッグの仕方](https://www.tipsfound.com/vba/01010), [メニュー(デバッグ)の操作方法\[ExcelのVBA\]](https://www.petitmonte.com/excel/excel_vba_11.html)

Comment: こんなほぼ変更無しという記事 [バージョンの違いによるマクロの違いについて（Excel2003から乗換え予定の方へ）](http://www.start-macro.com/55/w/s025.html) がありますが、一方でこうした相違点を書いた記事 [Excel2003からExcel2010に移行するにあたって](http://kiruah.sblo.jp/article/54657245.html) もあります。何か参考になれば。あとExcel2010(Office2010)はサポート終了ですので、なるべく最新のものに移行した方が良いでしょう。[Office 2010は「2020年10月」にサポート終了。今使っているバージョンを調べるには？](https://dekiru.net/article/19387/)

Comment: バージョンアップしてもマクロ機能はほとんど変更ないのですね。色々情報を頂きましたので参考にして調べてみます。